# Can I use wildcards in the extension for Git LFS tracking?

Tags: git, git-lfs

It's possible with Git LFS to use wildcards to track all files for a given extension. E.g.

```
git lfs track "*.jpg"
```

However, we have 3rd party software that produces binary files with a variety of extensions but they start the same. E.g. file1.xyzaaa, file2.xyzbbb, file3.xyzccc.

Is it possible to use a wildcard in the extension name? E.g.

```
git lfs track "*.xyz*"
```

That would be most useful!

Answer (score 0):

That (trailing wildcard in file extension) is not one of the tested use cases in [`filepathfilter/filepathfilter_test.go`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/c5951464d8fbd9f9e84dfc2dd703670ac8469a78/filepathfilter/filepathfilter_test.go).

So if it does not work, that would be an [issue to add in the git-lfs project](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/search?q=wildcard&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).